# How to show and make own play control youtube embed from IframePlayerAPI, trigger by scroll event

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

if I use this

```
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('video-placeholder', {
         width: 600,
         height: 400,
         videoId: 'zYdquUPcRSw',
         playerVars: {
             color: 'white',
         },
   });
}

function myFunction() {
    console.log(player);
    player.playVideo();
}
```

it works, but I want youtube show when scroll event is triggered, so I add line code like this,

```
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
     window.onscroll = function() {
         player = new YT.Player('video-placeholder', {
             width: 600,
             height: 400,
             videoId: 'zYdquUPcRSw',
             playerVars: {
                 color: 'white',
             },
         });
     }
}

function myFunction() {
     console.log(player);
     player.playVideo();
}
```

It works, youtube show just when I scroll the window, but function `playVideo()` don't work (note: `playVideo()` there is inside `myFunction()`). after I try to show `player` variable with `console.log(player)`. I see that there is no function inside the variable like this :

[image: console log]

different result when I dont use window.onscroll function, if I use console.log to variable player, the result is this :

[image: console log 2]

is it possible to do it "show and make own control youtube with youtubeIframeAPI and triggered by scroll event" ?

Comment: This can be due to multiple initiations of YT.Player because it is on scroll, try limiting it to only firing it once after the first scroll.

Comment: @AbhishekKumarTiwari I thought maybe because scroll event fire multiple times, but I have changed with another event that only just fire once, I change "scroll" event to click event to BODY element, it still the same, it only works if I use event "load".